# How to create a class array in typescript/ javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class car

```
export class Car{
    no:number;
    name:string;
}
```

I want to make a class array of type Car[] .

```
let cars: Car[] = new Car[5];
```

But this is not possible. I do not want to create arrays of type:

```
let cars: Array<Cars>
```

Or

```
let cars = []
```

As they make variable of type 'Array' but I want the variable type to be 'Car[]'.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say `I want the variable type to be 'Car[]'` but that's exactly what you're doing by writing `let cars: Car[]`. What's wrong? Also, `let cars: Car[]` and `let cars: Array<Car>` (not Cars) is the same thing, as far as I know

Comment: `Car[]` as a type is exactly the same as `Array<Car>`. How you write it, is just preference. That said, creating an array of cars always involves creating an *array* of objects of type `Car`. No magic here.

Comment: `new Car[5];` `5` represents an index value here. not size.

Comment: what I am asking is how to make the datatype of newly created variable of car as 'Car[]' and not 'Array'. Here by above method it creates type of variable car as 'Array' but not what I want it to be as 'Car[]'.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong here. Creating an array and declaring it to be of type `Car[]` is the most you can get out of this. It will always be an array. The type `Car[]` literally means *"array of cars"*.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to quickly create, say 5, cars. As implied by `let cars: Car[] = new Car[5];` then this is not possible. You will need to create those 5 cars *by hand* or by loop. No shortcuts here.

Comment: Yes this will be still array but I want it of type Car[] but here it gives me of type Array instead of type Car[].

Comment: I give up. Sorry... Don't want to repeat my self again.

Comment: @DindayalPandey arrays are dynamically sized in JavaScript, so `let car: Car[] = [];` should be sufficient for your needs here.

Comment: What do you mean, "gives me of type Array"? Who gives it to you? How do you ascertain this? Why is this relevant? If it is during execution, note that TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, and JavaScript has no concept of `Car[]`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCdoG8BQ1oDsD2AuLArgLYBGApggNzpZhFn4QAuCAlpgObUC+qqAbomjBEEfPAQBtALrQAvNBnUAZtiQAKEGSbRW86AAZKu6AB5oAVmMBqa6wCUKGiIQRJrWQsxkA7nETq9jxAA

Answer (score 4):

You can set the type and declare it as an empty array

```
let cars: Car[] = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have:

```js
class Car extends Array {
    constructor(length: number, public no: number, public name: string) {
        super(length);
    }
}

const cars: Car[] = new Car(6, 42, 'Batman');
```

Please keep in mind, you problem might be an XY problem.

It is a bad practive to extend native built ins.

I have never used smth like that in my code.

I believe you should not do it either.